# How to run docker on the Mac command line?

Tags: macos, docker

I have installed docker for a Mac, and in order to execute a simple test I seem to have to run all of these steps:

1. Run `docker-machine start` to start the docker daemon(?)
2. Run `docker-machine env` to get a list of environment settings.
3. Run `eval $(docker-machine env)` to set these settings
4. Finally you are able to run an example like `docker run hello-world`
5. And you have to remember the terminal you run all of these commands, as running the same example from within a different terminal won't work.

Is that the correct way on how you start the daemon or setup the machine/terminal in order to use docker? Or is there a more easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have installed [Docker Toolbox](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox) rather than [Docker for Mac](https://www.docker.com/docker-mac).

Once Docker for Mac is [installed](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/#download-docker-for-mac) it provides a more streamlined experience. The Linux VM is largely hidden from you and doesn't require VirtualBox to run.

The `docker` command will connect to the new VM by default without setting up the environment as the docker socket from the VM is mapped through.

```
→ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  daemon  57  1 Nov 00:02 /var/run/docker.sock -> /Users/matt/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/s60
```

Comment: So after I have installed `Docker for mac` I just can do commands like `docker run` or `docker ps` from any terminal?

Comment: Yep. The docker socket from the VM is shared to the system